# REF Cursor from Procedure PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to troubleshoot a PL/SQL package. I found a similar example to explain my question as I am new to learning PL/SQL and how a cursor works with a procedure.

So for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE emp_by_job (
    p_job           VARCHAR2,
    p_emp_refcur    IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
    OPEN p_emp_refcur FOR SELECT empno, ename FROM emp WHERE job = p_job;
END;
```

In this I see that p_job is defined as VARCHAR2. Then the SQL selects from EMP where job = p_job. All we've defined p_job as is VARCHAR2, not mapped to a field anywhere. How does the cursor know what to do with job = p_job, where does p_job's value come from?

Thank you!

Comment: `p_job` is the first input parameter of your procedure.

Comment: But where does that input get it's value?

The cursor is selecting from EMP where job = p_job, p_job is an input, where does it's value come from?

Comment: It gets the value from whoever is calling it. You can do a search in all_source for it.

Comment: Thank you, turns out the procedure was being called from a SQL file external to the DB so I didn't see the call in ALL_SOURCE

Comment: I'd say this applies to all procedures/functions/subroutines in all programming languages ever written, not just PL/SQL. You pass in values as parameters and the code does something with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A procedure doesn't **do** anything when it is compiled, it needs to be called/invoked. The value for `p_job` will be passed when the procedure is called. In the example below, `emp_by_job` is invoked from an anonymous pl/sql block with a value for the argument `p_job` of 'MANAGER'.

```
koen>CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE emp_by_job (
  2      p_job           VARCHAR2,
  3      p_emp_refcur    IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  4  )
  5  IS
  6  BEGIN
  7      OPEN p_emp_refcur FOR SELECT empno, ename FROM emp WHERE job = p_job;
  8  END;
  9* /

Procedure EMP_BY_JOB compiled

koen>set serveroutput on size 999999
koen>DECLARE
  2    TYPE emp_t IS REF CURSOR;
  3    l_emp emp_t;
  4    l_emprow emp%ROWTYPE;
  5  BEGIN
  6    emp_by_job(p_job => 'MANAGER',p_emp_refcur => l_emp);
  7     LOOP
  8        FETCH
  9           l_emp
 10        INTO
 11           l_emprow.empno,
 12           l_emprow.ename;
 13        EXIT
 14     WHEN l_emp%notfound;
 15        dbms_output.put_line(l_emprow.empno || ' ' || l_emprow.ename);
 16     END LOOP;
 17  END;
 18* /
7698 BLAKE
7782 CLARK
7566 JONES


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

koen>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detail. It helped me understand the problem.

What I was looking for was being passed by a piece of SQL being invoked by a batch file therefore I didn't find what was making the call to my procedure that was passing in the value I was looking for! 

It seemed like it was coming out of thin air but now I see where it is being called/ passed from.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped